# Can you use independent R and Python chunks in RMarkdown Kaggle Kernels? (without reticulate syntax, '$' operator)

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, kaggle, reticulate

I'd like to use the R Notebook shorthand described [here in an RStudio blog post](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/10/09/rstudio-1-2-preview-reticulated-python/) and [here in the RMarkdown Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/notebook.html) which allows independently executable Python and R chunks in R Notebook documents. Is this possible to set up inside of a Kaggle kernel that uses RMarkdown?

I've tried the below so far in a fresh Kaggle kernel with no success:

```
{r setup, include = FALSE}    
    library(reticulate)      
    use_python('../../usr/bin/python3.5')
```

```
{python}
    import pandas # error: 'pandas/import unrecognized...etc'
```